# linux refused to mount a valid partition

Tags: linux, mount, lvm2

My setup is a linux box with 1 partition used thought LVM - has been working for years.

I add a freeze and after the reboot the partition cannot be mounted:

> **mount -r -t ext3 /dev/pve/data /mnt/pve-data**
>
> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/pve-data,
>         missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>         In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>         dmesg | tail  or so

However fsck doesn't see any problem with it:

> **fsck.ext3 -fp /dev/pve/data**
>
> /dev/pve/data: 3024076/60366848 files (0.6% non-contiguous), 156921642/241435648 blocks

There's nothing in dmegs nor the syslog.

I'm puzzled, what's wrong with my partition?

Thanks in advance

greg

debian 5.0.10

LVM 2.02.39

Comment: Have you done what was suggested in the error message and check the syslog output and/or dmesg?

Comment: Thanks @mdpc ! the partition was labelled ext3 in fstab but file -s confirmed it's in fact ext4. I don't know why it used to mount and doesn't anymore. Please add an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partition in question probably is ext4 and not ext3.  Thus when the mount command notices this and then gives the error.

Comment: I'm amazed mount didn't see that. I must say I tried mount without specifying the fs type and I got an error message asking me to.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the filesystem you are trying to mount has a loaded driver.

###### Run under root (or via sudo):

to get the filesystem type

> blkid

```
root@kontron:~# blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="9de9be9f-04c9-4542-b0e0-3f9a2cb1c785" TYPE="ext3"
/dev/sda5: UUID="0958ee8b-55d8-462a-8dcf-1674c7212690" TYPE="swap"
```

to list loaded kernel modules

> lsmod

```
root@kontron:~# lsmod | grep ext
ext3                   94204  1 
jbd                    32269  1 ext3
mbcache                 3762  1 ext3
```

if module isn't loaded try finding it under the corresponding modules folder

```
ls -la /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs
drwxr-xr-x 59 root root  4096 Jul  7 13:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root  4096 Jul  7 13:42 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jul  7 13:42 ext2
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jul  7 13:42 ext3
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jul  7 13:42 ext4
```

*Please note that if you are executing tese under initramfs sometimes it requires installing additional kernel modules and rebuilding the initramfs

try loading the necessary module

```
modprobe -v ext3
```

and repeat the mount

```
mount -r -t ext3 /dev/pve/data /mnt/pve-data
```